# kohana 3.2 database query with sql port from 2.3

Tags: php, sql, kohana

I am trying to port a database query from an application that was running in Kohana 2.3 to a new application running in Kohana 3.2. In spite of reading the Userguide and looking at many examples on Google I am totally confused by the query builder.

In the Kohana 2.3 application there is the following code

```
$query = "SELECT w.id as wid, wc.id as wcid, w.*, wc.* FROM widgets as w INNER JOIN widget_controls as wc ON w.id=wc.widget_id
                WHERE wc.position_id=1  AND wc.supplier_id = '".$supid."' AND wc.status = 1
                ORDER BY wc.display_order ASC";
$result = $db->query($query);
```

I understand that the $db->query no longer exists in 3.2 and it has become something like DB::select

I would really appreciate it if anyone could give me a bit of guidance on how to convert this sql query to a form that would work in 3.2.

Kind Regards

Richard

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DB::query()` method: http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/DB#query